# Get a video from youtube for a corresponding userid

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, youtube-api

i am using different userid in the following url -"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userid/uploads" but i cant get video belongs to that corresponding user intead of that i am gettting following error 
"Execution of request failed: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ashok/uploads"
i need to know why these kind of exception is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got message: `User's` account is closed`

for more details please take a look youtube API

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Comment: whats the another option for that